# How can I compute a conditional sum in my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sum, rails-activerecord

Say I want something *like* this in Rails:

```
class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base
    def interest_level
        self.yes_votes.count - self.no_votes.count
    end

  private
    def yes_votes
        self.votes.where(:vote => true)
    end

    def no_votes
        self.votes.where(:vote => false)
    end
end
```

1. What have I *basically* done wrong in the code above? (I realize it's probably terrible in numerous ways.)
2. What's the correct way to do this from a Rails standpoint?
3. What considerations should I be mindful of from a database standpoint? (e.g., even if code like the above *were* possible, I'm guessing it would be excessive on the DB side. But naturally I'm not really sure.)

Comment: Are you specifically asking for Rails 3 ( I took cue from `.where` )?

Answer (score 2):

class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base

```
def interest_level
    self.votes.sum('votes', :conditions => {:votes = true}) - self.votes.sum('votes', :conditions => {:votes = false})
end
```

end

thanks,
Anubhaw

Comment: This doesn't make much sense.  In fact I think it won't even work, it would generate, if rails allowed it, two queries like this: `SELECT SUM(votes) FROM votes WHERE votes = true AND proposal_id = ..`   Which would fail (no column named `votes`).  The method in the question would generate the correct SQL: `SELECT count(1) FROM votes WHERE vote = true AND proposal_id = ..`

Answer (score 2):

Considering the database loading i recommend to implement a custom counter cache. I would do like this:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base

    def after_create
      self.update_counter_cache
    end

    def after_destroy
      self.update_counter_cache
    end

    def update_counter_cache
      self.proposal.yes_votes_count = self.proposal.votes.where(:vote=>true)
      self.proposal.no_votes_count = self.proposal.votes.where(:vote=>false)
      self.propsal.save
    end
end
```

Please note, you have to add two columns to your `Proposal` model.

```
add_columns_migration.rb

add_column :proposals, :yes_votes_count, :integer
add_column :proposals, :no_votes_count, :integer
```

Comment: This would work, but it's more complex, more prone to failure, and its performance relative to the method in the question would be based on how often votes are updated or changed.  Adding votes or changing them using this method would incur a larger cost.

Comment: Yes definitely involves larger cost, but I think the cost is still smaller than doing two join queries on each page load. Also the good solution depends on your needs, how you should change a vote, or create.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see anything overtly wrong with your code.  Though there are a number of ways to accomplish what you seem to be trying to do, your method seems like it should work fine (though I have limited experience with Arel).

Another way to go about this might be simply changing the `interest_level` method:

```
def interest_level
    self.votes.count - self.no_votes.count * 2  # same as (total - no_votes) - no_votes
end
```

The above *might* be slightly quicker, though I highly doubt it will make much difference, count queries are pretty fast on indexed columns, and your version of that method is easier to read